# How to get only field value in View template

Tags: 7, views, theming

How can I access/print the raw value of a date field? (or any field for that matter). I am working in a View template and I typically use `$fields['field_myfield']->content`. But that gives me the HTML not just the value.

My template.php file:

```
 function mytheme_preprocess_views_view_fields(&$variables)
{
    $view = $variables['view'];
    if($view->name == "news_main_list")
    {
          $variables['news_date'] = $variables['fields']['field_news_date_text']->content;
          $variables['news_type'] = $variables['fields']['field_news_type']->content;
          $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][]='views_view_fields__news_main_list__block_1'; 
     }
 }
```

My views-view-fields--news-main-list--block-1.tpl.php file:

```
  <?php if (!empty($field->separator)): ?>
<?php print $field->separator; ?>
```

```
  <?php print $field->wrapper_prefix; ?>
<?php print $field->label_html; ?>

<p class="newsTitle"><?php print $fields['title']->content; ?></p>
<p class="dateByLine">
    <?php print $news_date; ?> | <?php print $news_type; ?>
    <?php if ($news_type == "event") : ?>
        <?php print 'hello'; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</p>

  <?php print $field->wrapper_suffix; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must specify which one of Views template files you are working on, If it is `views-view-fields.tpl.php` then `$fields` variable is availabe but if it is not `views-view-fields.tpl.php` then `$view` object is available. use `kpr($variable)` to get the `$variable` available properties.

You can also use `hook_preprocess_views_view_fields(&$var)` to set the values of fields in `$var` array then retrieve them in fields template file

---

**UPDATE:**

First define the following function in your `template.php` file

```
    function THEME_preprocess_views_view_fields(&$variables)
    {
        $view = $variables['view'];
        if($view->name == "THE_VIEW_NAME")
        {
              $variables['my_field'] =strip_tags( $variables['fields']['field_myfield']->content);
              $variables['title'] =strip_tags( $variables['fields']['title']->content);
              $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][]='views_view_fields__SOMETHING'; 
         }
     }
```

By this function the `$my_field` and `$title` variables are available in the `views-view-fields--SOMETHING.tpl.php` file. You have to create `views-view-fields--SOMETHING.tpl.php` file in your theme directory and use above variables in it. `views-view-fields--SOMETHING.tpl.php` file is created to theme every output (record or row of columns) of your View. Make sure you are using `-` instead of `_` when creating `views-view-fields--SOMETHING.tpl.php` file.

`$view` variable is a variable that contains every detail of the current View. you can use `kpr($view)` to see its results.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26050/discussion-on-answer-by-drupalist-how-to-get-only-field-value-in-view-template).

Answer (score 0):

if you want, you can use variable $variables. In file template, use code

```
dpm($variables)
```

and see that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the raw value, and you're in a Views Row template (usually somehow overriding `views-view-fields.tpl.php`) you can use the $row object to get the associated fields.

In this case, you can try `$row->field_field_myfield[0]['raw']['value'];`

Comment: Thanks, is there another way to do this without setting UND to 0, and actually using 'raw'. I've read that this is bad practice.